# What is the appropriate ActiveRecord "Where" syntax for SQL "in"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following piece of code that's broken:

```
 //user_posts_id is an array of integer values
    @comment_notifications = Comment.where(["author_id != ? and post_id in ?", current_user.id, user_posts_id])
```

This is part of the error:

> PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near "1" LINE 1: ...
>   "comments" WHERE (author_id != 8 and post_id in 1,4,8,9,2,... ^ :
>   SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE (author_id != 8 and post_id
>   in 1,4,8,9,2,3)

It doesn't seem to work because of the second conditional for "posts_id" and "user_posts_id". Also the "!=" complicates things a little, I think. What would be the appropriate way to write this ActiveRecord query?

Appreciate any suggestions! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are sending the list without parens.

```
 @comment_notifications = Comment.where(["author_id != ? and post_id in (?)", , current_user.id, user_posts_id])
```

If you look at the error it's telling you that the problem is near the "1", which is the first item in your list.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in Rails other way also :

```
@comment_notifications = Comment.where
                                .not(author_id: current_user.id)
                                .where(post_id: user_posts_id)
```